# Java Microsoft Insight Connection String from config file

Tags: java, spring-boot, config, azure-application-insights

I have following folder hierarchy in project:

```
- src
  - main
    - profile
      - dev
        - osoz-config.properties
      - prod
        - osoz-config.properties
```

I have connection string for each environment. How can i set up them from these files?

I know that i can try via file applicationinsights.json or environment variable. Also i read about TelemetryConfiguration, but it is not available in newest verions

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the latest versions and configured `TelemetryConfiguration` to my springboot application.

[image]

**ApplicationInsights.json:**

```
{
  "InstrumentationKey": "your-instrumentation-key",
  "TelemetryChannel": {
    "DeveloperMode": false
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Endpoints": {
    "LiveMetrics": "https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track"
  }
}
```

- The below code involves loading the configuration from `ApplicationInsights.json`.

```java
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.TraceTelemetry;

public class javatestapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load the configuration from ApplicationInsights.json
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.getActive();

        // Initialize TelemetryClient
        TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

        // Create and send a custom trace
        TraceTelemetry traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry("Sample Trace");
        telemetryClient.track(traceTelemetry);

        // Flush the telemetry and stop the application
        telemetryClient.flush();
        telemetryClient.getContext().getTelemetryConfiguration().getChannel().stop();
    }
}
```

- To store your connection strings for each environment you can also use `osoz-config.properties` as below.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ConfigurationManager {
    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH = "profile/%s/osoz-config.properties";

    public static Properties loadProperties(String profile) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        String filePath = String.format(PROPERTIES_FILE_PATH, profile);

        try (InputStream input = ConfigurationManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)) {
            if (input == null) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filePath);
                return null;
            }
            properties.load(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return properties;
    }
}
```

**Transaction search:**

[image]